# Verbo "slittare": come si deve usare quando ha il significato di rinviare una riforma?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Secondo il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/slittare/) il verbo "slittare" ha questo uso figurato:

> Nel linguaggio politico-amministrativo, *fare slittare l’applicazione o l’esecuzione di una norma legislativa*, rinviarla. Con il sign. di essere rinviato, anche nell’uso com.: *la riunione di oggi è stata sospesa, e slitta alla prossima settimana*.

Non capisco bene però come si deve usare questo verbo con questo senso. Secondo il Treccani si tratta di un verbo intransitivo, ma nell'esempio "slittare l'applicazione di una norma" sembra farne un uso transitivo. Mi confonde anche il fatto che il Treccani dica che l'ausiliare può essere "avere" o "essere". Quindi, questa frase sarebbe corretta?

> Hanno slittato la riforma dell'Università.

Comment: “Slittare” transitivo mi suona strano; hai visto qualche esempio di questo uso o è una tua ipotesi?

Comment: @DaG: Quando il Treccani dice "slittare l’applicazione o l’esecuzione di una norma legislativa", questo non è un uso transitivo?

Comment: @Charo L'esempio non è *slittare l'applicazione* ma *far slittare l'applicazione*, cioè *far sì che l'applicazione slitti*. Cfr. *far scivolare qualcuno* e non *scivolare qualcuno*

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quindi, "l'applicazione" è il soggetto di "slittare" e non il complemento oggetto?

Comment: @DenisNardin: E la frase corretta dovrebbe essere "Hanno fatto slittare la riforma dell'Università"?

Comment: @DenisNardin:  Potrei anche dire "La riforma dell'Università ha slittato"?

Comment: @DenisNardin: O forse  "La riforma dell'Università è slittata"?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quello dell'ausiliare che può essere "avere" o "essere" mi risulta confuso.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che Denis abbia ragione: il verbo è intransitivo. Tuttavia, ho dei dubbi su come usare questo verbo.

Comment: @Charo Credo che la cosa che ti confonde qui è che non è una proposizione semplice ma un periodo: *Fare* ha come complemento oggetto la proposizione *slittare l'applicazione*, mentre *l'applicazione* è soggetto di *slittare*. In inglese sarebbe *make the application delay*. Per rispondere alla tua altra domanda io direi *La riforma dell'università è slittata* (anche se mi suona più idiomatica *È slittata la riforma dell'università*, con l'inversione tra soggetto e verbo).

Comment: @DenisNardin: Adesso capisco che "l'applicazione" è il soggetto di "slittare". Prima non era chiaro per me perché ho pensato che fosse simile a "rinviare" ("rinviare l'applicazione di una norma", qui il verbo è transitivo).

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quindi questo verbo si usa con l'ausiliare "essere" (perlomeno quando ha questo senso)?

Comment: @Charo Io almeno lo userei solo con "essere", ma lungi da me contraddire il dizionario Treccani.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La frase

> Hanno slittato la riforma dell'Università.

è errata; la frase corretta è:

> Hanno fatto slittare la riforma dell'Università.

Infatti il verbo slittare è intransitivo, e il verbo principale della frase è *fare*, e non *slittare*.
È la riforma dell'università che slitta, ovvero si sposta in avanti nel calendario.
Qualcuno, il soggetto imprecisato della frase, la fa slittare.
Alla fine si dirà che la riforma è slittata, con l'ausiliare essere.